# Android-10 DeepLink is not working, but works below android 10 versions

Tags: android, deep-linking, androidx, android-10.0, deeplink

I am working on an android app where i am staring the login activity with deep link url
and here is the intent i am using .

```
  <activity android:name="Login_User"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter
            android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>

            <data
                android:host="www.mySite.com"
                android:path="/launch.php"
                android:scheme="http"
               ></data>
            <data
                android:host="www.mySite.com"
                android:path="/launch.php"
                android:scheme="https" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

this code works on all android version except android 10 ,
what should i do to make it work on android 10 . I can't find something specifically for android 10.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you were previously executing something like "scheme://host/path", but I believe Chrome doesn't handle that URI scheme for Android 10 and later. This is now the recommended scheme:

intent://host/path#Intent;scheme=scheme;package=com.example.app.package;end

See this reference: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

I've also found [this tool handy](https://codepen.io/nsorosac/pen/LEdGQq) for seeing working examples on my mobile device. For your app, you could try launching this URL from javascript or a web browser:

```
intent://www.mySite.com/launch.php#Intent;scheme=http;package=your.app.package;end
```